# What is an alternative way to write great-great-great-grandfather using numbers?

Tags: word-choice

I find this notation cumbersome as the read has to count the "greats". Is there maybe an alternative notation which states the fourth ancestor generation explicitly?

Comment: Yes, you can call your great great grandfather you second great grandfather, the ggg grandfather you third great grandfather, and so forth. Standard genealogical terminology.

Comment: Many computer guys would be tempted to write `great**3 grandfather`, or maybe even `father**5`.

Comment: Genealogy programs handle well all id’s of people using numbers.

Comment: I hope there is none.

How could you find that notation cumbersome?

If you're interested in genealogy, why not work within the established rules? If this isn't about genealogy, what are you Asking about?

Why not try "4-times grandfather" or whatever arithmetic construct works for you?

If you do that, how d'you think it will fit with the general genealogy community?

Answer (score 2):

Funny you should ask. My spouse just discovered that her **10th great grandmother** was born in Bolton Castle, England, and was the sister of the first Lord of Baltimore. She and her husband emigrated to the nascent colonies at Jamestown.

This is the terminology used by Ancestry.com for genealogical purposes. So, the ancestor in question was my spouse's great great great great great great great great great great grandmother, i.e., **10th great grandmother**.

Comment: I think that’s all there is to it!

Answer (score -1):

I've come up with an even easier solution, and that is to simply consider every "great" as a number and then write the number in superscript before the word. For example, my IVGrandfather was my great, great, great, great grandfather. Now, in text you should make the number a superscript, but I can't do that here in this response box. This is how I do it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).